# What is the set $\mathbb{Z}\backslash 2 \mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation

I have not taken group theory and was confused by a notation

$$\mathbb{Z}\backslash 2 \mathbb{Z}$$

Can someone please help me to understand this and its possible generalization?

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't written $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$? What you have looks like the set of all odd integers, or in other words, the integers minus the integral multiples of $2$.

Comment: @MichaelMorrow Yes, so why do you think there is a mistake in the question? It denotes the set of odd integers. Why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix $n\in\Bbb N$.

---

The set

$$\Bbb Z\setminus n\Bbb Z=\{x\in\Bbb Z\mid x\notin n\Bbb Z\},$$

where

$$n\Bbb Z=\{ny\in\Bbb Z\mid y\in\Bbb Z\}.$$

---

The group

$$\Bbb Z/ n\Bbb Z=\{x+n\Bbb Z\mid x\in \Bbb Z\},$$

where $n\Bbb Z$ is as above, is understood as a group under the operation

$$(a+n\Bbb Z)+(b+n\Bbb Z):=(a+b)+n\Bbb Z.$$

It is a [quotient group](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_group). Each of its elements is what is known as a [coset](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coset) of $n\Bbb Z$.

---

Your case, of course, is when $n=2$.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ \ $n \mathbb{Z}$ might also refer to the orbit space of some action of $\mathbb{Z}$ on $n  \mathbb{Z}$, right?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{Z}$ be the set of all integers.

We want to put all integers into $ n$  distinct buckets and two integers belong to same bucket if they are similar.

Now, it is meaningless until we define what does it mean by the word "similar " and "bucket".

Two integers $a$ and $b$ are similar $(a\thicksim b)$ if $a-b$ is divisible by $n$.

It is easy to check that the relation is an equivalence relation.

Then the equivalence class(bucket) of $a$,

$[a]=\{b\in \mathbb{Z} : b\thicksim a \}$

$a\in \mathbb{Z} $ and $n>1$ by division algorithm,
$\begin{align}
a&=nq+r
&(q: quotient, r:reminder,0\le r\le ( n-1) ) \end{align}$

$a-r=nq$ and hence, $a\thicksim r$

$\implies [a]= [r] $

Hence, there is $n$ distinct equivalence classes $[0], [1],..., [n-1]$.

Then the set of all equivalence classes $\{ [0], [1],..., [n-1]
\} =\mathbb{Z}/ \mathbb{nZ}$

In your question, $n=2$

$\mathbb{Z}/ \mathbb{2Z} = \{ [0], [1] \}$

Two integers belongs to same equivalence class iff they leave the same reminder upon division by $2$.

Like, $2\in [0] $ because both are divisible by 2.